# Pandas Dataframe: adding Integer column to another Integer column without NaN error

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I want to add two columns with:

````
```
month1['Energy stop (wh)'] += diff
month1['Energy consumed (wh)'] += diff
```
| Index |     Values| 
| :---- |      ----:| 
| 17634 |     2735.0| 
| 2     |     5433.0|
| 17639 |      811.0| 
| 4     |     6116.0| 
| 8     |    12247.0| 
|       |           | 
| 17618 |    11047.0| 
| 35171 |     2249.0| 
| 17633 |    12565.0| 
| 35172 |    11158.0| 
| 35204 |     3600.0| 
Name: Energy consumed (wh), Length: 2053, dtype: float64
````

and I want to add a column with less values, not every value of the first table(above) is in the one I want to add.

```
| Index|    Values| 
| :----|    ----: | 
| 3    |     30300| 
| 4    |     46450| 
| 5    |     42751| 
| 7    |     14682| 
| 10   |      7526| 
| 1847 |    181066| 
| 1865 |     44012| 
| 1878 |    356825| 
| 1879 |     34404| 
| 1891 |    -17275| 
Length: 171, dtype: int64
```

how can I add those two Dataframes without touching the values that are not in both tables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer `merge` on the column `Index` like so :

```py
df = pd.merge(df1,
              df2,
              how='outer',
              left_on=['Index'],
              right_on=['Index'])
```

If `Index` is the actual index for both DataFrames, you might rather use `left_index` and `right_index` :

```py
df = pd.merge(df1,
              df2,
              how='outer',
              left_index=True,
              right_index=True)
```